# What serializer is used when session state is set to Sql Server and can I change it?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, serialization, web-config

We want to use Sql Server session state, but we have already designed many of our objects to be serialized through WCF which uses the DataContractSerializer. I don't know what serializer the Sql Server session state uses but if it's the XmlSerializer then I'm afraid it might not work with the way our objects are designed.

Does anyone know which serializer it uses and if it can be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it can be changed. See this [info from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx).

> To perform data serialization and deserialization, ASP.NET uses two
>   methods depending on the types involved. For basic types, ASP.NET
>   resorts to an optimized internal serializer; for other types,
>   including objects and user-defined classes, ASP.NET makes use of the
>   .NET binary formatter. Basic types are String, DateTime, Boolean,
>   byte, char, plus all numeric types. For these types, a tailor-made
>   serializer is used that is faster than the default and general-purpose
>   .NET binary formatter.
>
> The optimized serializer is neither publicly available nor documented.
>   It is nothing more than binary read/writer and employs a simple but
>   effective storage schema. The serializer uses the BinaryWriter class
>   to write out one byte to denote the type and then the value. While
>   reading serialized bytes, the class first extracts one byte, detects
>   the type of the data to read, and then resorts to a type-specific
>   ReadXxx method on the BinaryReader class.

Doesn't look like it's serializing to XML. Just binary. Although note that was written in 2003, over a decade ago!

Comment: Thanks, I think we've decided to try to use the DataContractSerializer up front and then save/retrieve that value to the session. We'll see how that goes in a few minutes :)

Comment: Why bother? ASP.NET handles storing and retrieving it for you. Introducing your own solution has the potential to cause bugs and/or slow down the code.

Comment: Because we're using WCF and our objects were created with the knowledge that WCF uses the DataContractSerializer. Different serializers work differently, and it's unlikely that asp.net is going to use the DataContractSerializer so it's not going to serialize properly.

Comment: When you say "not going to serialize properly" you mean that you expect it to serialize to a certain format, for some outside reason. But when ASP.NET serializes for saving session state, that is literally the only purpose it has is to save and retrieve that object's state. So it should not matter to you what format it's using, only that it works. And it definitely does work, because saving objects to the Session with SQL Server as the storage provider has been done millions of times now. It's battle tested. There's no need to concern yourself with the particular details.

Comment: Right, but it does matter how it's serialized. One nuance of the DataContractSerializer is that it doesn't run the constructor nor any other static initialization. And the XmlSerializer, by default, will serialize different properties than the DataContractSerializer. It would have been ideal to use the DataContractSerializer since we already had attributes for the properties we wanted serialized and some other details of implementation were designed for it that would apply differently with the way any other serializer (such as binary) works.